# How to do one hot encoding if there is only one distinct value in categorical feature

Tags: pyspark, one-hot-encoding

I need to do one hot encoding for a categorical variable "day of week" in my dataset, but sometimes the dataset only have one value such as "Wednesday", how to do one hot encoding in this case?

Comment: You will be more likely to get useful responses if you include a (*small*) sample of the data, and a code sample illustrating what you have tried and why it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

1. If the column is completely populated with only on value - Why do you need to the one Hot Encoding, that columns is not telling any useful information and is redundant in any Machine Learning Exercise
2. If the columns has 2 Values, Null & Wednesdays, The hot encoding code works, and will give a binary column, of 1/0 where 0 will be representing the value which occur more frequently (Null/ Wednesday)

Comment: because this is a test data and not for training the model, sometimes, we only have one day data, so that's why "day of week" doesn't have two values